# WAMP all subdirectories are not found

Tags: wamp, subdirectory

My WAMP server is not serving up subdirectories... I get a `Not Found The requested URL ... was not found on this server.` message. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Show the actual message in its entirity. Show the url you are trying to use. In short you need to give more details if you want an intelligent answer.

Answer (score 0):

IIS and Apache/Wamp are both web server and might conflict in some way, so you have to disable IIS in order for Wamp to work

Disable IIS in Vista:

Control Panel, Uninstall Programs, Turn Widows Features On or Off, uncheck Internet Information Services

Disable IIS in XP:

Control Panel, Add/Remove Programs, Add/Remove Windows Components, uncheck Internet Information Services (IIS)

Restart computer, then restart Wamp

Also, open file hosts in folder C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc and delete anything in there and have only this line and nothing else

127.0.0.1 localhost